# When trying to convert a JSON file to CSV, I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, csv

So, I have a JSON file that I've extracted from my instance of CloudHealth. I want to take the contents of the file and dump it into a CSV file. When I try to do this, I get an error that list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I have seen multiple people ask this question, but the answers never seem to actually work or often don't make sense. Am I supposed to explicitly call something an integer?

I've tried using for loops to iterate through each line. I've also tried using writerow with the column headers and JSON values. Below is my current version of my script.

Here is a portion of the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "allocation_id": "eipalloc-0fd72e57a49a91e83",
        "association_id": "eipassoc-019ab2294484f268d",
        "domain": "vpc",
        "id": 6116033436809,
        "is_active": true,
        "network_interface_id": "eni-06441888c03f4afc2",
        "network_interface_owner_id": "375497951801",
        "private_ip_address": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "public_ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
     },
]
```

```
import csv, json

with open('/response.json') as infile:
    ipInfo = json.loads(infile.read())

with open("/response.csv", "w") as outfile: 
    f = csv.writer(outfile)
    f.writerow(["allocation_id", "association_id", "domain", "id", "is_active", "network_interface_id", "network_interface_owner_id", "private_ip_address", "public_ip"])
    f.writerow([ipInfo["allocation_id"], ipInfo["association_id"], ipInfo["domain"], ipInfo["id"], ipInfo["is_active"], ipInfo["network_interface_id"], ipInfo["network_interface_owner_id"], ipInfo["private_ip_address"], ipInfo["public_ip"]])
```

Right now, the headers for CSV file are added, but the column content is not.

This is the error that I see:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with either pulling the data from your response.json file or the data itself. Could you share the contents of this file? Also, I would recommend loading data from a file this way instead
`with open('/response.json') as infile:
    ipInfo = json.load(infile)`

Comment: Okay, I've added a small portion of response.json. When printing ipInfo, it shows the contents of the json file.

Comment: Do you understand what a `list` is, and how to index it?  And how that's different from a `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample input you added to your question, it appears that the JSON file contains a *list* of JSON *objects* — as opposed to being a large single object — which get turned into a Python list of dictionaries by `json.load()`....and because of that, you should use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) instead of a `csv.writer` to write the CSV output file.

So here's what I think would be the way to do what you want:

```
import csv
import json

fieldnames = ("allocation_id", "association_id", "domain", "id", "is_active",
              "network_interface_id", "network_interface_owner_id",
              "private_ip_address", "public_ip")

with open('./response.json') as infile:
    ipInfo = json.load(infile)

with open("./response.csv", "w", newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(ipInfo)
```

Note that if you didn't want to hardcode the fieldnames into your code as shown, you could probably extract them from the first object dictionary in the returned list like this:

```
    fieldnames = ipInfo[0].keys()
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks! As I'm still learning lists and dictionaries through Python, I was confusing myself on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the JSON, `ipInfo` is not a dict, but a list of dicts - one for each desired line in the CSV, presumably.

You can make the `csv` module do more of the work for you, by using the provided `DictWriter` and telling it what the headers are:

```
with open("/response.csv", "w") as outfile: 
    dw = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields=[
        "allocation_id", "association_id", "domain", "id", "is_active",
        "network_interface_id", "network_interface_owner_id",
        "private_ip_address", "public_ip"
    ])
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(ipInfo) # N.B. writerows, plural
```